# Json to php get a exact value

Tags: php, json

I want to get the

```
http:\/\/www.adorocinema.com\/_video\/iblogvision.aspx?cmedia=18638261&amp;isApp=true
```

from this :

```
"trailerEmbed":"<div id='ACEmbed'><iframe src='http:\/\/www.adorocinema.com\/_video\/iblogvision.aspx?cmedia=18638261&amp;isApp=true' style='width:480px; height:270px' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen='true'><\/iframe><br \/><a href=\"http:\/\/www.adorocinema.com\/filmes\/filme-109815\/\" target=\"_blank\">Pequena Miss Sunshine<\/a><\/div>"
```

How?
thanks.

Comment: if you ever tried something, then show us to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that using jquery :

```
var url =  $("div#ACEmbed").find("iframe").attr('src');
```

if you want to do it in php I think the following code would work :

```
$iframe = "<div id='ACEmbed'><iframe src='http:\/\/www.adorocinema.com\/_video\/iblogvision.aspx?cmedia=18638261&amp;isApp=true' style='width:480px; height:270px' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen='true'><\/iframe><br \/><a href=\"http:\/\/www.adorocinema.com\/filmes\/filme-109815\/\" target=\"_blank\">Pequena Miss Sunshine<\/a><\/div>";

preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/', $iframe, $match);
$url = $match[1];
```

Comment: @SilviuFuicu Updated the answer hope it helps

Comment: you idea lead me to this                                                                       `$iframe_id = new SimpleXMLElement($iframe_code);
    $iframe_link = $iframe_id->iframe['src'];
 echo $iframe_link;`                                                                                         thanks~